# Диагностировать у кого (кому)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Диагностировать у кого (кому)?

Answer (score 2):

Диагностировать у кого? что? Пример: Диагностировать у больного ангину.

Comment: Извините, Вас не затруднит указать источник информации? Я не могу найти это слово в словарях управления.

Answer (score 0):

Словари управления, оно, конечно, солидно. И доказательно. Но если нетути... 
Обычное врачебное употребление: диагностировать у кого, но поставить диагноз кому.